# nginx+django+uwsgi static files 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, nginx, static, uwsgi

Hi~ I'm deploying a website in CentOS 6.5. The framework is django1.7. I use nginx and uwsgi.

The website is now available except 403 Forbidden for all static files.

I have googled a few hours, and have changed the whole site folder as chmod 777. The owner of folder is kltc, and user in nginx.conf is also kltc.

I have no idea why the problem is still Permission denied.

> nginx.conf

```
user  kltc;
worker_processes  1;
```

> kuaileticao.miyayx.me

```
 server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen 80;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name kuaileticao.miyayx.me; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        charset utf-8;
        access_log /srv/www/nginx/kuaileticao.miyayx.me/access.log;
        error_log /srv/www/nginx/kuaileticao.miyayx.me/error.log;

        location /static {
            autoindex  on;
            alias /home/kltc/Project/sunny_sports/sunny_sports/static; 
        }

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8001; 
        include uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
    }
```

> uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# the base directory (full path)
chdir=/home/kltc/Project/sunny_sports
# Django's wsgi file
module=sunny_sports.wsgi:application
master=true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes=10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket=127.0.0.1:8001
chmod-socket=664
chown-socket=kltc:kltc
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
# clear environment on exit
vacuum=true
max-requests=5000
daemonize=sunny_sports.uwsgi.log
```

> error.log

```
[error] 34335#0: *73 open() "/home/kltc/Project/sunny_sports/sunny_sports/static/css/font-awesome.min.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 157.7.154.194, server: kuaileticao.miyayx.me, request: "GET /static/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1", host: "kuaileticao.miyayx.me", referrer: "http://kuaileticao.miyayx.me/"
```

> ```
> [kltc@localhost static]$ pwd
> /home/kltc/Project/sunny_sports/sunny_sports/static
> [kltc@localhost static]$ ls -l
> total 32
> 4 drwxrwxrwx.  2 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 25 18:51 avatars
> 4 drwxrwxrwx.  7 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 25 18:51 css
> 4 drwxrwxrwx.  2 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 25 18:51 custom
> 4 drwxrwxrwx.  2 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 25 18:51 font
> 4 drwxrwxrwx.  2 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 25 18:51 fonts
> 4 drwxrwxrwx.  3 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 25 18:51 images
> 4 drwxrwxrwx.  2 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 25 18:51 img
> 4 drwxrwxrwx. 10 kltc kltc 4096 Feb 26 08:18 js
> ```

>

```
[kltc@localhost static]$ ps -aux | grep nginx
root     37444  0.0  0.0 110008  2048 ?        Ss   09:02   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
kltc     37445  0.0  0.0 112548  3700 ?        S    09:02   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

I have tried several methods. Such as, change the nginx.conf user to `root`. But none of them worked.

Hope for your help. Thank you!

Comment: What do you receive at `error.log`? Also, it may help if you chown parent directory to be readable by the nginx worker.

Comment: error.log has many lines like this :  `2015/02/26 09:02:49 [error] 37445#0: *11 open() "/home/kltc/Project/sunny_sports/sunny_sports/static/js/jquery.hotkeys.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 101.20.9.33, server: kuaileticao.miyayx.me, request: "GET /static/js/jquery.hotkeys.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "kuaileticao.miyayx.me", referrer: "http://kuaileticao.miyayx.me/"
`

Comment: I solved the problem after taking the advice from @supermario. It's because the permission of  /home dir.  Thank you very much!

Comment: This tripped me before. Happy to help. I added the answer then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that you chown parent directory of your project (/home) to be readable by the nginx worker.

```
chown -R kltc:kltc /home 
chmod -R ug+r /home
```

Comment: Solved my problem as well, basically all parent dirs need to be readable by the designated nginx user.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the STATIC_ROOT declared in your settings file.

Also, try running `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`before running the server.

Hope that works!