# Django; display problems for image of model object passed to template from view

Tags: django, templates, nginx, view, media

Created new item with name, description and an image with django admin and attached image and I saw the image pop into the media folder on the server as it was uploaded.  I passed the item from view to template.  The item name, description showed up in the website but the image ('image.jpg') did not.  Any ideas?  Maybe nginx is causing the image to stay concealed?  I'm using nginx, gunicorn, django.

note: on Chrome, it shows a torn image icon.  The source code on the browser shows `<img src="image.jpg/">`.   I noticed that the static files are in the format : `<img src="static/app1/image123.jpg` and display fine.  Perhaps my problem image should have media/app1/...?

My ultimate goal is to disaply a graph/image BUT this image is frequently overwritten, with changes, in the media folder from a separate app on the server.  This way the viewer can get the latest image.

abridged file structure, for easy viewing:

```
-website1
-media
 image.jpeg
+static
-app1
 -templates
  -app1
   index.html
   layout.html
-website1
 settings.py
 ..
```

website1 urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from website1 import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('app1/',include('app1.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app1's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
]
```

settings.py:

```
...
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT= 'media/'
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

from PIL import Image
from django.core.files import File
from django.conf import settings
from io import BytesIO
import os
from app1.models import Item

def index(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request,'app1/index.html', {
        'Data':now,
        'itemContext':Item.objects.get(id=1)
    })
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'app1/layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1 align="center">{{Data}}</h1>
<h2 align="center">
    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% static "sentiment_analysis/image.jpeg" %}" alt="No immage"/>
</h2>
<h4>

    {{itemContext.name}}
    {{itemContext.description}}
    <img src="{{ itemContext.image }}"/>

</h4>
{% endblock %}
```

app1's models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

nginx/sites-avilable.conf:

```
...
...
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

location /static/ {
    alias   /home/jeff/website1/static/;
}

location /media/ {
    alias /home/jeff/website1/media/;
}
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLUTION WAS A FILE PERMISSIONS ISSUE... SEE COMMENTS]**

in the image src you have double double quotes so the src isnt working replace it with that and you should be good

```
<img src="{% static 'sentiment_analysis/image.jpeg' %}" alt="No immage"/>



eidt your code is like that 
<img src="{% static " #this quotes ends here 
sentiment_analysis/image.jpeg # this isnt inside any quotation 
" %}" # second quotation start and end here
```

## in here you should relace :

```
<img src="{{ itemContext.image }}"/>
```

## with this

```
<img src="{{ itemContext.image.url }}"/>
```

Comment: The line /image you pasted above works fine.  the line and image that pertains to my problem is <img src="{{ itemContext.image }}"/>, what exactly are you saying to fix?

<img src="{% static { itemContext.image } %}" alt="No immage"/>

??

Comment: just put single quotes inside double quote the whole sentiment_analysis/image.jpeg isn't actually inside any quotation check my edit

Comment: I changed to single quote, the image shows with double or single quotes.  Your solution does not work... I actually had the itemContext.image.url in the past but as I tried things I forgot to put it back.  Still does not work.

Comment: when you right click from the source code  and open in new tab does it open or you get 404 ?

Comment: Right click what?  If it's the image, then if I try to open the broken image icon in a new window if gives a 403-forbidden error

Comment: its probably a server permission problem  it's not django problem thi should solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732692/nginxdjangouwsgi-static-files-403-forbidden

Comment: As soon as I saw the forbidden, I started searching for stackoverflow for django-permission issues too.  Thanks LeLouch, for the link to that site.  The permissions on the actual image allowed user and group to read but when I changed other to be able to read then the image worked.  So this problem is solved, at least temporarily, with 'sudo chmod -R o+r image.jpg'. I'm guessing Django deliberately enforced this security... for reasons I don't know... yet.