# Static files not found error deploy django nginx gunicorn ubuntu 18.04

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, deployment, static

I'm a python Django developer and I'm facing a problem in my deploy. THE SERVER IS WORKING NORMALLY, BUT IT DOES NOT FIND AND DOES NOT RECOGNIZE THE STATIC FILES. I'm using an ubuntu 18.04 server.

I made all the necessary configurations: I created the file gunicorn.socket and the gunicorn.service and they are already working normally.

The next step was to create the `server{}`. At the moment, I haven't applied https and security, I just want to access the server by the same ip, in an http way. My file is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    location /static/ {
        root /root/myproject;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /root/myproject/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

The user is: `root`

The root path of my project is this: `/root/myproject`
-> It doesn't have the `/home` folder like it usually does. I already checked it

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'templates/static'
]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

Regarding the settings in settings.py, I already put the `STATIC_ROOT` and I already made the `python manage.py collectstatic`

Another detail: I put the `{% static load %}` and the `{% static 'css/file.css' %}` normally. When I run the application on my pc, local server, everything works normally. I think the error is on the `server{}`

Another thing. Setting `DEBUG = True` or `DEBUG = False` didn't interfere with anything

I've run `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx` so many times I've lost count. And it still didn't work

UPDATES: I PUT THE FILES:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;

error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
```

AND I RECEIVED THIS: Permission denied:

```
2023/04/29 08:05:33 [error] 22531#22531: *2 open() "/root/analistamines/static/css/loginregistro.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ... , server: IP_EXTERN , request: "GET /static/css/loginregistro.css HTTP/1.1", $
```

Anyway, if anyone can help me solve this problem, I'd be very grateful

Comment: `root /root/myproject/static;` and you need to run `collectstatic` first to collect all static files into a single directory.

Comment: Already did that. I deleted the static folder and ran `python manage.py collectstatic` again and it still doesn't recognize it

Comment: I posted an error and got a permission problem: `2023/04/29 08:05:33 [error] 22531#22531: *2 open() "/root/analistamines/static/css/loginregistro.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 191.187.137.244, server: 54.39.238.17, request: "GET /static/css/loginregistro.css HTTP/1.1", $`

Comment: I put my static files in the var/www/static/ folder make sure you set the correct paths in settings and give full permissions to the folders

Comment: @gaviaostack: well then likely your web users has no permissions to access the directories or files in these directories.

Comment: how do you give full permissions to folders?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open() "/root/project/static/\*.css" failed (13: Permission denied) nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495218/open-root-project-static-css-failed-13-permission-denied-nginx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732692/nginxdjangouwsgi-static-files-403-forbidden